# Why does Transfer Learning cause the error/loss to restart from random after pre-training is completed?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was experimenting with Transfer Learning today, and don't understand some of the results I got. I trained a Convolution Neural Network on around 100,000 rows of Word2Vec embeddings, and saw a large gap in variance in my results.

[image: Training step 1]

The focus of the graph here are the lines at the bottom. The first 15 epochs were cut from the graph, but the trend is still visible. The training loss decreased over multiple epochs, and validation loss converged easily.

Evidently, this is a variance problem between train/dev error. To solve this, I knew that adding more data is the easiest solution to it. But since my laptop does not have enough ram to hold twice the amount of data in a single process, I decided to load in a second set of data (from the same distribution), and use transfer learning to re-train the model that got the results above from 400 epochs.

These are the results after running the process for around 100 more epochs

[image]

I don't understand the results here. Since I am using Transfer Learning on a data that comes from the same distribution, shouldn't the starting loss be closer to 0.35 instead of 0.41. Likewise, the f1 score which I was monitoring started with values closer to 0.78, and eventually went to around 0.85, while after 400 epochs on training on the previous dataset, the f1 measure was about 0.88. Why is this the case?

One thing I am familiar with is that transfer learning from a pre-trained network usually relies on "freezing" the weights from the lower-level layers, and only updating the dense layer weights. I am not doing this here, but that is because I want the algorithm to learn the low-level features from the new data points as well. Why does the starting loss restart after the pre-training has been completed?

Comment: and where is the code?

Comment: I think that the Model architecture will help more:

Comment: 128-Conv layer,
64-Conv layer,
32-Conv layer,
16-Conv layer,

Flatten,

0.5 Dropout,
256-fully connected layer,
Batch Norm,
Relu activation,

0.5 Dropout,
Output layer with Sigmoid. 

There is also early stopping with Validation loss on training